# Efficiently replacing Pandas dataframe with values from other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

There are 3 sets of dataframe code below:

```
dataset = {
        'X1': [18, 70, 70, 65, 18],
        'X2': [1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
        'X3': [45, 55, 22, 31, 23],
        'X4': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
        'X5': [65, 80, 500, 200, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)


dataset1 = {
        'Variable': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'],
        'Label': ['Age', 'Sex', 'Ethnicity', 'Education', 'Income']}

df_labels = pd.DataFrame(dataset1)


dataset2 = {
        'Variable': ['X1', 'X1', 'X1', 'X4', 'X4', 'X2', 'X2', 'X5', 'X5'],
        'Code': [18, 70, 65, 1, 2, 1, 2, 65, 80],
        'Value': ['18-24', '70-90', '65-80', 'Degree', 'Masters', 'Male', 'Female', '65K', '80K'] }

df_values = pd.DataFrame(dataset2)
```

**df**

[image]

**df_labels**

[image]

**df_values**

[image]

I wrote the following code to replace the values in the df dataframe, using the df_values table.

```
df["X1"].replace({18: "18-24", 70: "70-90", 65: "65-80"}, inplace=True)
df["X2"].replace({1: "Male", 2: "Female"}, inplace=True)
df["X4"].replace({1: "Degree", 2: "Masters"}, inplace=True)
df["X5"].replace({65: "65K", 80: "80K"}, inplace=True)
```

This resulted in this dataframe:

[image]

This replacement was simple because there is only 4 sets of replacements to a few variables. However, the dataset contains nearly 100 variables. Is there an easier method to replace all the values (for all 100 variables) using the df_values table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create nested dictionary by columns names and then use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
d = (df_values.groupby('Variable')
              .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Code')['Value'].to_dict())
              .to_dict())

df = df.replace(d)
print (df)
      X1      X2  X3       X4   X5
0  18-24    Male  45   Degree  65K
1  70-90  Female  55  Masters  80K
2  70-90  Female  22   Degree  500
3  65-80  Female  31   Degree  200
4  18-24    Male  23  Masters  100
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) after pivoting the replacement dataframe

```
df.replace(df_values.pivot(*df_values).T)
```

---

```
      X1      X2  X3       X4   X5
0  18-24    Male  45   Degree  65K
1  70-90  Female  55  Masters  80K
2  70-90  Female  22   Degree  500
3  65-80  Female  31   Degree  200
4  18-24    Male  23  Masters  100
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I will be attempting this step too.